# .html.erb set div doesn't work correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html

I just created a `scaffold` in rails and list all `stories` in index page, and `_stories.html.erb` is partial which was rendered in `index.html.erb`

I want each story div has a red background for example:

```
.storyCell{
    background-color:red;
    height:100px;
}
```

**_stories.html.erb**

```
<tbody>
        <% @stories.each do |story| %>
        <div class="storyCell">
          <tr>
            <td><%= story.content %></td>
            <td><%= story.finished %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Show', story %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_story_path(story) %></td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', story, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
          </tr>
        </div>
        <% end %>
      </tbody>
```

But the result is the red div all in top of the story model properties. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is invalid html. You can't have a div inside a tbody. Remove your div, and just put the class directly on the table row:

```
<tr class="storyCell">
```

What's happening here is that the browser is trying to do the best it can to render the invalid html, and so it pulls the div out (which it nows is not allowed inside the table) and renders it above the table instead.

Answer (score 1):

You can give the class to `<tbody>` like this:

```
<tbody class="storyCell">
```

Here is the w3schools example you can look at: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_tbody
.You can't insert div in table elements as it will render in correct html output.

Comment: If i add this class "storyCell" on `tbody` the height seems not work.

Comment: That has to do with your css.